# Error when trying to add Entity Data Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

every time I go to "add new item" --> "entity data model (.edmx)" and select my PC and Database (the test connection button says "success") and hit "add" I get this error. What is my problem?

[image]

Comment: If you create a different DB and point it at that, do you get the same error?

Comment: Don't know if this is at all related, but I saw this - might be worth a read:  http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/08/fixing-the-server-explorer-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-error.html